# what is the Android P+ compatible substitute for this non-SDK interface ->'android.webkit.PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE'

Tags: android, webview, android-11

I am getting following error;
Non-SDK API Usage Violation
Your app uses 1 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+.
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I

I am getting above error if I add following line in android webview code
request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});

App was crashing, so I commented few lines, and then uncommented one by one and found that the above error messsage is shown for following line
request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});

I wanted to know what is the substitute for this non-SDK interface which is compatible with Android P+